# Jest not recognizing .jsx files when running on Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo

I'm having trouble getting jest to run its test suite on .jsx files from my Expo program.

My babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/babel.config.js",
      "!**/jest.setup.js"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
    "@mantine/hooks": "^3.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "expo": "~43.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "jest-expo": "^43.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've also tried adding `@babel/preset-react` to `presets`, but the error message changes to the following:

```
    [BABEL]: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
```

I do not have a webpack.config.js or a jest.config.js.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, I would be grateful.

Thanks!

Edit: I've added '@babel/preset-react' to my babel.config.js file, and now I'm getting an error from jest that says 'add @babel/preset-react' to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. My updated babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', '@babel/preset-react'],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx']
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So I reinstalled all my dependencies and it seems to be working.... unsure what the issue was but it seems likely that I either deleted or broke a dependency file.